# Visual Studio for Flutter Development

Tags: flutter, mobile-development

I'm setting up my Flutter environment (Electric Eel Version), and I'm trying to decide if it is necessary to install Visual Studio for mobile development only. Because I know that Visual Studio requires a large amount of storage, but the Flutter doctor says that it is necessary for Windows development.

So, is it okay not to install Visual Studio for Flutter development? Does this affect my flutter environment or not?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1105], locale en- 
US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows. 
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
    Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
    Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, its not required for **mobile  development**. It does not effect your flutter environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing mobile apps, you don't need visual studio. And if you don't install visual studio, there is no problem for development.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually saying that if you want to develop your `Flutter` application for `Windows` you will have to install `Visual Studio`.

It will not effect your Flutter environment.